# Mysterious protocol not implemented warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, protocols

I am implementing a protocol that has a method called fbDidExtendToken:.
For some reason, I get the warning that I am not implementing this method.
Why is this?

In my .h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
//...
```

in my .mm

```
@implementation AppDelegate
//...
-(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken
{

}
```

Error message is:

> /Volumes/mchinen/scm/FindYourself/FindYourself/AppDelegate.mm:13:1:
>   warning: method in protocol not implemented [-Wprotocol,3]
>   /Volumes/mchinen/scm/FindYourself/src/Facebook.h:123:1: note: method
>   declared here [3]
>    - (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the protocol header file, it seems the entire method is

```
- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt;
```

and the xcode warning only gave me the method name up to the first parameter, which I copied and pasted to implement, causing the warning.